# Encrypt XML Elements with X.509 Certificates

Tags: c#, xml, certificate

I have copy the samples from msdn site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229943%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

I've created a certificate, but when i run the program i have this error in the Decrypt method: "Unable to retrieve the decryption key"

I've read somewhere that there is a bug in this sample because the Encrypt method don't save the decryption key.
The problem is that i don't understand how can i resolve the problem.

Can you help me please?

The crypted Xml obtained is:

![alt text][1]

I suppose the problem is that doesn't exists the keyName.

[1]: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c603c876e.png ""

I've generated the certificate as:
makecert -sk Abc -n "CN=Abc" -sr localmachine -e 06/22/2011 Abc.cer

Comment: I tried the sample in VS 2008 with target framework set to 3.5 and it worked as advertised. For what its worth, i'm running on Windows XP/SP3. I saw that the KeyInfo was saved into the file as expected.

Comment: How do you generate the certificate?

makecert -sk Abc -n "CN=Abc"  -sr localmachine -e 06/22/2011 Abc.cer

Answer (score 0):

ok, when i create the certificate i need to use this parameter:

makecert -r -pe -n "CN=XML_ENC_TEST_CERT" -b  01/01/2005 -e 01/01/2012 -sky exchange -ss my  cert.cer